# ODE time of life of a solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider following the ODE : $$x'=1-t^2+x^2$$

What is the time of life of a solution from this equation ? The Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem proves that a solution for the Cauchy boundary $x(0)=x_0$ lives in an open interval $(t_-,t_+)$, what can we say about $t_+$ ? 
I want to show that $t_+ < \infty$, because when I plot the related field I find that the slopes to the solution must be very slanted. But it remain impossible for me to produce a proof. If you know how to do it please tell me.

Thanks.

[I enter the wrong equation, there is a "minus" for the $t^2$ term]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.h.s. of your equation is strictly positive which means $x$ grows all the time at lest as $t^3/3$. Thus for large enough $t$ you can neglect  the $1+t^2$ term to get $x'\simeq x^2$ which can be solved $x=-1/(t-t_0)$ i.e. there is a pole for some finite $t_0$.

**After the change of sign in the initial question:**

With this sign there is a simple explicit solution:
$$\frac{2 e^{t^2} x_0}{2-\sqrt{\pi } x_0 \text{erfi}(t)}+t$$

i.e. there is always a pole for some $t$, except for the case $x_0=0$

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mistaken I enter the wrong equation, so there is a "minus" for the $t^2$ .. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was not ment for analytical resolution. I will provide a more general approach :

If we assume that $y(0)=0$ then $x(t)=t$ is a solution.

We assume that for example $y(0) \geqslant 0$. If we set $y(t)=x(t)-t$ then $y'(t)=y^2(t)+2ty(t)$.  Let $[0,T)$ be the maximal interval such that $y(t)>0$, and this is also the maximum interval for $x$ by Cauchy-Lipschitz (we can not cross the solution $x(t)=t$)

Then we obtain $y'(t) \geqslant y^2(t)$ and then : $$ \left( \frac{1}{y} \right ) = \frac{-y}{y^2} \leqslant -1$$ over $[0,T)$. Thus $T \leqslant \frac{1}{y(0)}$ is finite.

Finally if $y(0) <0$ we have :

$x'(t) \geqslant 1-t^2$ and then $x(t) \geqslant x(0) +t - \frac{t^3}{3}$ From the fact that $x'(t) \leqslant 1$ over the maximum interval $I=[0,T)$ where $x(t) \leqslant t$ by Cauchy-Lipschitz.

It follows that $x$ is bounded on every segment and then $I=\mathbb{R}_+$

I hope it is clear and that other members will appreciate this point of view.

Comment: Roughly speaking, as soon as $x(t)>t$, the behavior becomes essentially the same as the extremely fast growth exhibited by $x'=x^2$. This is the gist of your argument.